# Permissions on a folder

Tags: c#, xml, permissions, text-files, file-permissions

I have been looking for some time now and have not been able to find this.  How can I set my program up to write or update a file from multiple users but only one group is allowed to open the read what is in the folder?

```
class Log_File
   {
    string LogFileDirectory = @"\\server\boiseit$\TechDocs\Headset Tracker\Weekly Charges\Log\Log Files";
    string PathToXMLFile = @"\\server\boiseit$\scripts\Mikes Projects\Headset-tracker\config\Config.xml";
    string AdditionToLogFile = @"\Who.Did.It_" + DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year + ".txt";
    XML XMLFile = new XML();

public void ConfigCheck()
   {
       if (!File.Exists(PathToXMLFile))
       {
       XMLFile.writeToXML(PathToXMLFile, LogFileDirectory + AdditionToLogFile);
       }
    }
public void CreateLogFile()
    {

        if (Directory.GetFiles(LogFileDirectory).Count() == 0)
        {
            XMLFile.writeToXML(PathToXMLFile, LogFileDirectory + AdditionToLogFile);
            CreateFileOrAppend("");
        }
        else if (!File.Exists(XMLFile.readingXML(PathToXMLFile)))
        {
            XMLFile.writeToXML(PathToXMLFile, LogFileDirectory + AdditionToLogFile);
            CreateFileOrAppend("");
        }
        else
        {
            FileInfo dateOfLastLogFile = new FileInfo(XMLFile.readingXML(PathToXMLFile));
            DateTime dateOfCreation = dateOfLastLogFile.CreationTime;

            if (dateOfLastLogFile.CreationTime <= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1))
            {
                XMLFile.writeToXML(PathToXMLFile, LogFileDirectory + AdditionToLogFile);
                CreateFileOrAppend("");
            }
        }

    }

    public void CreateFileOrAppend(string whoDidIt)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore((IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly | IsolatedStorageScope.User), null, null))
        {
            using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(XMLFile.readingXML(PathToXMLFile), true))

            {
                if (whoDidIt == "")
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    myWriter.WriteLine(whoDidIt);
                }
            }
         }

      }
```

This is my path where it needs to go. I have the special permission to open and write to the folder but my co workers do not. I am not allow to let them have this permission.

If I where to set up a database how would i change this code

```
LoggedFile.CreateFileOrAppend(Environment.UserName.ToUpper() + "-" + Environment.NewLine + "Replacement Headset To: " + AgentName + Environment.NewLine + "Old Headset Number: " + myDatabase.oldNumber + Environment.NewLine + "New Headset Number: " + HSNumber + Environment.NewLine + "Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + Environment.NewLine);
```

I need it to pull current user, the agents name that is being affected the old headset and the new headset, and the time it took place.

Answer (score 0):

While you create file, you have to set access rules to achieve your requirements. .

```
File.SetAccessControl(string,FileSecurity)
```

The below link has example
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Also the "FileSecurity" class object, which is an input parameter, has functions to set access rules, including group level control.
Below link has example
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So I am going to do this as a Database but over several Tables. How can put line below in to a SQL database?      'LoggedFile.CreateFileOrAppend(Environment.UserName.ToUpper() + "-" + Environment.NewLine + "Replacement Headset To: " + AgentName + Environment.NewLine + "Old Headset Number: " + myDatabase.oldNumber + Environment.NewLine + "New Headset Number: " + HSNumber + Environment.NewLine + "Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + Environment.NewLine);'   This is just one example of what I need the log file to record

Comment: Sorry. I did not get you. Could you please give some more hint?

Comment: What I understood is, you are going to add the code snippet of function call in a SQL table. If so, I do not have much idea on that. But the security rules, you can add in your C#  source code as soon as you create the file.

Comment: Ok how would that be done? I am still having trouble with trying to get all of this coded so it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This question will be opened under a new question since I am going to take a different route for recording the data I need Thank you all for the help